# How can I see a file as it was at a particular git commit?

Tags: git

Given a file foo.m, how can I get Git to show me the complete contents of foo.m, as they were at some commit x?

Comment: That's a question for superuser.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git checkout sha1_here  -- foo.m
```

or without checking the file out and just viewing it from the command line

```
git show sha1_here:path_to_file/foo.m
```